# unable to read value written in mysql database using php using a php function, just after the function is called

Tags: php, mysql

In a php function, i tried to insert a row in a database table as

```
function abnc()
{

$link = conn to db;
$query = "insert into table( a,c ,v) values (1,2,3);"
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if(mysqli_rows_affected($link) == 1){
close conn;
return true;}
else{
return false;
close conn;
}
```

now, at other place, i called this function, and tried to read the values i had inserted
as

```
$done = abnc();
if($done)
{
$query = "select * from table where a=1 and c=2 and v=3";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
echo "true";
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
else
{
echo 'false';
}
```

the output i get is true0;

I think while the function was executing, the script just continued.
I want it to wait until function execution is finished.
Any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

The script does not continue. When you call abnc() that function will be executed and return a value which you store in the variable $done. This value is presumably true since your output is true0.

In abnc() you insert a row. Which means that one row was affected and the function returns true. And you close the db connection, which might be why you cant access your inserted data later.

Comment: but why cant it read the value, i just inserted ?? If i just go and execute the same query using phpmyadmin, i am able to see that it returns a row

Comment: @AmitMittal You close the connection in abnc(), I don´t see you connecting to the database again?

Comment: actually the function is in another file functions.php, which i had included in this file. AND IN THIS FILE, I opened A connection to database

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$done = abnc();
$link = conn to db;

if ($done) {
    $query = "select * from table where a=1 and c=2 and v=3";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        do {
            $resultSet = array();
            if (($row = mysqli_store_result($link))) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row)) {
                    $resultSet[] = $row;
                }
                $return[] = $resultSet;
                @mysqli_free_result($row);
            }
        } while (@mysqli_next_result($link));
        return $return;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You closed the database connection in your function try opening it outside the function and closing at the end of your script.